# Mixin for changing the behaviour of a get method in Django class based view

Tags: django, mixins, django-class-based-views

I'm attempting to write a mixin for setting a translation language based on the language set in the user Profile model. 
When a get request comes in, the mixin should set a language to user language, get response from the view that adds the mixin, and then set the language back to what it was before. I wrote the following mixin, which is invoked, but it's get method is not invoked. What am I doing wrong?

```
class SetUserLanguageMixin(object):
    def get(self, request):
        current_language = translation.get_language()
        try:
            translation.activate(request.user.profile.language)
            response = super(SetUserLanguageMixin, self).get(request)
        finally:
            translation.activate(current_language)

        return response

class SomeView(LoggingMixin, APIView, SetUserLanguageMixin):
    def get(self, request):
        ... 
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `SomeView` overrides `get()`, then your mixin's `get()` method will not be called unless you call `super()`. You could try overriding `dispatch` in your mixin instead.

Note that your view will be more robust if the overridden get/dispatch method accepts args and kwargs:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    response = super(SetUserLanguageMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

Comment: It works if I rename the get to say get_request in the view then call get_request from mixin's get. I have to "wrap" my get method (do some action before and after). I'm not sure overriding dispatch would work in this case.

Comment: Overriding [`dispatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) should achieve the same effect. When you call `response = super(SetUserLanguageMixin, self).get(request)`, the default implementation of dispatch is to call the method based on the `HTTP` method, i.e. `get()` for GET requests.

Comment: Thank you for adding an example. It does seem to invoke dispatch now if I place it before  APIView. rest_framework.views.APIView also has a dispatch method, so there's a conflict.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to get the order of your parent classes in the correct order so that they are called in the correct order.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a catch 22 because I need APIView to run first and populate the user object in the request, but that I guess is beyond the scope of my original question. Thank you for your help!